Comparison of area of boundary of geodesic balls using Bishop-Gromov
I met a question in a paper written by Cheeger-Colding-Minicozzi. They claimed that
$$
\frac{\operatorname{Vol}\left(\partial B_{R_1}(p)\right)}{\operatorname{Vol}\left(\partial B_{R_2}(p)\right)} \leq 2 n \quad\left(R_1 \leq R_2\right)
$$
For complete noncompact manifolds with $\operatorname{Ric}_{M^n} \geq 0$ and this is a standard consequence of the Bishop-Gromov inequality.
I don't know how to deduce this directly from volume comparison.

Note that this is not a volume comparison. It's a comparison between the $(n-1)$-dimensional volumes of 2 geodesic spheres. I suggest looking at the proof of Bishop-Gromov and see if you can use it to prove this inequality.
